# Curl desde wamp windows7 64bit sin respuesta sitio web externo

Tags: php, windows, curl, wamp

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de hacer un llamado a un sitio web utilizando curl, de php, desde windows 7 64bit, utilizando wamp v2.2 y php v5.4.3.
Esto me devuelve un null.
Si en el mismo código cambio la url por una local, el curl funciona.
Baje un fix para el curl pero el resultado es el mismo, en phpinfo el curl esta funcionando (de hecho funciona para una url local).
Hace ya dos días que estoy tratando de solucionarlo no se por donde seguir, muchas gracias.

```html
<?PHP
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://webservice...");

$response=curl_exec($ch);
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
    case 200:  # OK
      break;
    default:
      echo 'Código HTTP inesperado: ', $http_code, "\n";
  }
}else{
 $response=json_decode($response);
 var_dump($response);
}
curl_close($ch);/*

?>
```

Comment: Probaste con una url externa que sea http en lugar de https? Qué tenes en curlopts? Desde la maquina podes hacer un ping la maquina que hostea el servicio?

Comment: Gracias por contestar, probe con la siguiente url y me funcionó: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed    puedo pingear el sitio, no se cual es mi curlopts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a Juan por responder, pude solucionarlo gracias a tus preguntas, estoy haciendo esto desde un localhost a modo de prueba, luego necesitare un ssl pero eso es otra historia, solo agregue al código lo siguiente después del curl_init(); (No se si es lo mejor pero es lo que me resulto)

```html
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Exacto. Con veryhost debería ser suficiente.